# Git: Reverting multiple commits that are contiguous but not most recent

Tags: git, git-revert

I read [How I reverted several git commits in a single commit](http://archlinux.me/dusty/2011/02/26/how-i-reverted-several-git-commits-in-a-single-commit/), and that's exactly what I want as the result. However, I do want to revert all in one commit because 1) there're many commits to be reverted 2) it's likely that I need to revert the reverts later.

I got luckier than the example in the link, as there weren't commits to be retained in the middle of those to be reverted. This is what my history looks like:

```
A–C1–C2–C3–C4–O1–O2–O3
```

where the four C commits are the ones I want to revert, and the O commits were made by other authors later.

How can I revert the four C's in one commit R, which can be reverted later to have all C's in effect again?

Comment: If the O commits were made by others, changing the C commits means you are rewriting the history of the repository. This is never recommended (specially if the repository is public). Are you sure that is that what you want to do?

Comment: @LucasSaldanha I'm not changing the C commits. I just want one R commit at the end of history that says "revert all C commits". And the O commits are irrelevant to the C commits.

Comment: Ah now I get it. I believe that @durek gave you a correct answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so many git commands, [`git revert` uses `git rev-list` (or the moral equivalent thereof) to parse its arguments](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html): see in particular the description of **OPTIONS**.  This means, among other things, that you can simply pass a range of commits, as spelled out in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  Remember that `C1..C4` excludes `C1` itself<sup>1</sup> so if you're using this form, write `C1^..C4` or `A0..C4`.

That takes care of specifying which commits to revert, but still leaves you with a revert that makes four new commits:

```
$ git revert 22b38d1^..676699a
```

does not do what you want.<sup>2</sup>  What you want is also listed in those **OPTIONS**, and is just `-n` (or `--no-commit`, same thing):

```
$ git revert -n 22b38d1^..676699a
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
You are currently reverting commit 22b38d1.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)
[remainder snipped]
```

All four commits are now reverted but no commit has been done so now I must manually commit the result.  If I run `git revert --continue` git will make a commit for me, but will only mention the *first* reversion (`22b38d1`, in this case—the reversion is done in reverse, with `676699a` done first in case that's needed to revert the previous commit, and so on).

```
$ git commit
```

This brings up the editor with a "reverts (the first commit)" message, which I can now fix to say "revert 22b38d1^..676699a in one swoop".  (Constructing a good reversion message can be difficult; git's default for automatic commits is adequate, but the default in this case, with `-n`, is not.)

---

Git being git, of course, you can use this same technique *without* the `-n` and *with* the `git rebase -i` mentioned in your linked posting: squash together the four reverts into one single revert, but use the squash action to combine the commit texts.  Here you might run:

```
$ git revert --no-edit 22b38d1^..676699a
[messages omitted]
$ git rebase -i HEAD~4
[editor runs: change last three to "squash", write, exit editor]
[editor runs again: edit commit message to describe 4-in-1 reversion]
```

You might prefer this second method (I think I prefer it myself, it's just not quite what you asked for).

---

A side note on this: `git rebase` simply *copies* (as if by cherry-picking) commits, using temporary, anonymous branch.  To use your notation, you start with:

```
A – C1 – C2 – C3 – C4 – O1 – O2 – O3   <-- branch
```

and acquire, after the four reverts (without `-n`, making four new commits), this:

```
                                     R4 - R3 - R2 - R1   <-- branch
                                    /
A – C1 – C2 – C3 – C4 – O1 – O2 – O3
```

where the R's are the reversions of the C's.  The rebase then copies the original R's, tacking the copy (which, in this case, ends up being just one commit which I'll call `R`) on at the point the rebase starts-from, and moving the branch label so that it points to the last of the new commits (making the temporary branch permanent again):

```
                                     R4 - R3 - R2 - R1   [abandoned]
                                    /
A – C1 – C2 – C3 – C4 – O1 – O2 – O3 - R   <-- branch
```

What happens to `R1` through `R4`?  They've been abandoned and are eventually<sup>3</sup> garbage-collected.

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless you use `--boundary`, but that marks the boundary commits with `-` in `git rev-list` output.  I have not tested this with `git revert`: the hat suffix to move back one commit in the graph is sufficient, and is what I generally use for these cases.  (It fails if you reach a root commit but that's not going to happen here.)

<sup>2</sup>Not just because those particular commit hashes are unique to the repository I ran these commands in, either.  Your hashes will be different; or you can use relative names like `HEAD~6^..HEAD~3` or equivalently `HEAD~7..HEAD~3`.  This assumes your drawing of the commit graph fragment is accurate and you haven't done anything since then to move `HEAD`.

<sup>3</sup>The old commits are still find-able via the reflogs for `HEAD` and for your branch.  This keeps them around for 30 days by default, after which the old reflog entries expire and are deleted and *then* a `git gc` (including any automatic ones git does as needed) will remove those commits.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a thorough comparison between the options! Super helpful.